# What would be a good metaphysical component for a spell?

Tags: magic

Magic varies from story to story, but in most universes there's a price to pay for magic. The RPG system D&D sums it up three very ellegant categories:

- Vocal: some magic words, like *Abracadabra*;
- Somatic: some gestures, like those required in early Naruto *jutsus*;
- Material: some stuff, like bat wings, rat tails or fresh tears from a virgin.

I'm proposing the **metaphysical** component.

This type would be composed of things that can't really be touched or measured, like emotions, thoughts or even memories. Some good examples are:

- Happiness;
- Hope;
- Dread;
- A traumatic memory;
- A fresh idea...

---

The rules for you to propose a component are simple:

1. **State the spell you want to cast**, like *Expecto Patronum*;
2. **State the component this spell will need**, like *a happy thought*;
3. **State why is it needed**. Our example works because dementors feed on happiness;
4. **State the effect the spell has on the caster**. If happinness is consumed, is the caster suddenly sad? Tired? Unable to laugh for x hours/days?
5. **State a side-effect in case the spell backfires**. Ideally, this should be  a much worse cost than what you stated in item 4 (the caster gets heavily depressed. Suicidal even!) in order to keep things coherent, but feel free to make any kind of side-effect, as long as it's very bad.

**You can choose any spell you can think of** but if it's not a generally known spell (like casting a fireball) you have to explain how it works.

**You can use as many components as you deem fit** (even non-metaphysical ones), as long as you give a good explanation for them to be required by the spell.

**It is not required that the component comes from the caster himself**. So if you propose something like *true love*, the caster can use a young couple as his components. If you choose to do so, remember items 4 and 5. They apply to everyone involved in the spell but you get to decide how harsh they are for both the mage and his components.

Comment: May I recommend the _Dresden Files_ as interesting reading for such components.

Comment: Hello Magus, and welcome to Worldbuilding! You may want to edit the question and actually *ask a question* instead of farming out a statement of work. As it is, you seem to want to externalize *your* task to the community. Inventing the world is *your* task; what this site is about is checking whether the world is plausible enough, or helping with a particular difficulty.

Comment: Hello @AlexP. The poin't wasn't really to try and farm some stuff for a story. I just thought it would be cool to see what components people could come up with. It was more of a game-like scenario. Is that not allowed?

Comment: @Magus: Stack Overflow isn’t really a forum: it’s a question and answer site. You ask one question, you get some answers, you accept one answer. Worldbuilding is a bit more free-form than most stack overflow sites, but we try our best to adhere to the question/answer format. You might want to check out the help centre for more info, but for now I’m going to vote to close (it can be revoked if the question is edited) as it’s unclear what you’re asking. You might also want to think about how broad the question is, as ‘Make me a spell with a metaphysical component’ is a bit much.

Comment: @JoeBloggs Thanks for the clarification. I will edit the question and try to make it objective.

Comment: Am I missing something?  This reads like a very well scoped and specific question.  I'm voting to reopen unless someone can help me understand.  Those 5 rules for the proposed component overcome POB entirely.

Comment: I'm afraid you have changed a "Primarily Opinion Based" question into a "Too broad" question. This is not a brainstorming site, we can't provide you a spell list for your story. We aim to give "right" answers to questions. If I answer giving an example following your rules for the "Fireball" spell, and another user answers with an example of the "Invisibility" spell, which would be the *right* answer?

Answer (score 4):

I'm not really sure I can give a good answer to this question but some of my favourite non-physical components from various stories are, in no particular order; the light of creation, a perfect sunset, a sunbeam, "value" originally in the form of crushed gems but paper money works too, age, and the old classic lifespan.

Comment: I like the perfect sunset as a spell component. You can only cast the spell at a certain time of the day, and only on certain days.

Comment: @TylerS.Loeper I seem to recall it had been captured and was it a glass bottle actually.

Comment: @ Ash, That is too cool.

Answer (score 2):

**Animate an object**
You need:

- The object to animate (like a wooden puppet or set of armor)
- A mechanical clockwork (as substitution of a heart)
- The soul of an unborn child (it must have never experienced its own body in our world, so it can be transplanted into the object)

Effect if the spell fails: the unborn soul will possess the caster and take over his/her body.

Comment: I imagine an 80 year old wizard failing the spell, dropping on the floor kicking legs crying for breastmilk. Genius.

Answer (score 2):

**Eternal love potion**
You need:

- Eyeballs of eyes the target considers beautiful (you know, make beautiful eyes at her...)
- A heart filled with honey and sewn shut (sweetheart...)
- A set of golden rings (for obvious reasons)
- Loyalty (like that of a dog or a faithful servant)

Cook all ingredients for half an hour over a flame and *somehow* get her to drink this concoction while you wear one of the rings.

If the spell fails, she will hate you forever.

Answer (score 1):

**Lock door**

This spell actually effects the hinges of an object and blocks any movement of them. Can be cast on doors, windows, treasure chests or any object with hinges.

You need:

- Chalk to draw a magical sign on the inside (or indoors side) of the object
- The stubbornness of a mule

To break the spell, either remove the magical sign from the inside or cast the counterspell. For the counterspell you need:

- Coal to draw a magical sign on the outside of the object
- The strength of a bull

If the *close* spell fails, the hinge disintegrates and the object falls apart.  If the *open* spell fails, the hinges stay blocked.

Comment: If the open spell fails the hinges stay blocked **forever**. Fail the spell on purpose and lock whoever is inside for eternity.

Comment: That's why removing the sign from the inside automatically breaks the spell. It's like a panic room, nobody comes in but you can always get out.

Comment: But the spell was overriden by another spell, whose sign you cannot remove.